# connect three.js project to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, three.js

A have a quick quesion about three.js. So now I'm working with 3d project that uses a datbase connection, I use mysql for the first time. Did anybody had an experience on connecting three.js to mysql or other databases? That's important for me to start learning the product. I used to work with unity and blend4web.
If anyone has some special experience on it like some feathures to simplify process etc many thanks will be given!!!

Comment: Since three.js is a client-side js library, it will not be able to deal with databases directly, you will need some server side technology (such as python or php) to generate the content that will be loaded by one of the loaders on the client side. Apart from this, I do not really understand what exactly you are after. SO is for specific programming problems (such as I have a piece of code, it returns an error, can you pls help me to fix it), we do not do tutorials.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I didn''t found any information about my question in three.js manual and googling as well, so I asked it here. Thank you for linking to php, that gives me a decision. Sorry for stupid questions, my coding experience was paused for 6 years and now I need to use it again, thats why many simple things becoming a great problems for me :)

Comment: Anyway thank you. The problem is solved